# Minecraft - /give command not working with multiple enchantments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Using this command works fine:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:2000}]}
```

Using any of these doesn't work:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:2000},{id:"minecraft:looting",lvl:30s}]}

/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:2000}{id:"minecraft:looting",lvl:30s}]}

/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:2000}],[{id:"minecraft:looting",lvl:30s}]}
```

Did they change something? The first of the previous 3 used to work. The other two were me just messing around trying to guess the syntax. This is happening in 1.19.1 Java, singleplayer and cheats ARE enabled (obviously, as the first command works), it's only after trying to add multiple enchantments that it fails.

Using an anvil to combine them doesn't work as the anvil drops the enchanment level down.

*****EDIT*****

Somebody edited both the body and title of my post to completely change both the question title and body. Please don't do this - it changes the answers I'll get!

As for "/minecraft:give" - this appears to be a StackExchange edit because I copied and pasted directly from a text file and these commands start ONLY with /give in the text file.

These commands do not work, even in vanilla minecraft:

```
give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Unbreakable:1,Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:20},{id:"minecraft:looting",lvl:30}]}

give @p netherite_pickaxe {Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:unbreaking",lvl:255},{id:"minecraft:fortune",lvl:50},{id:"minecraft:efficiency",lvl:5}]}
```

If I switch to 1.16 or 1.17, they work fine...

Comment: Is the `s` at the end of the looting level supposed to be there?

Comment: No - No idea why that's there actually. However removing it doesn't help :(

Comment: My edit: [Removed the tag from the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), [Removed fluff such as "hi" and "thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/566903), removed the version number from the title since it was already in the body. None of those are "completely chang[ing] both the question title and body." If you don't trust me and want to validate for yourself, here is [the version before I edited](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/398692/1) and here is [my edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/398692/2)

Comment: Thanks for a relatively detailed question so far! It appears there may have been a misunderstanding. From what I can see, you have posted the commands with the `minecraft:` at the start of them from the very beginning. A second user edited to remove the greetings and signoff; your commands remained untouched by their edit. When you noticed that the commands had `minecraft:` at the start of them, you incorrectly attributed this to the second user's edit, when the error was in fact introduced before you submitted the post for the first time. You can review a post's history on the revision log.

Comment: This is *close* to being a good question, but there are some outstanding problems. First, you did not use `code font` on the commands you added in revision #3. I have fixed this problem with as little intrusion as possible, but feel free to edit further if you believe necessary. Second, you did not provide the error messages that occur when you run all these incorrect commands. Error messages are *required* when presenting a command that does not work; otherwise we have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: You are very close to having a perfect question! What I would suggest you to do is to check the revision history of the question by touching [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/398692/revisions). This will allow you to view all edits that each user made, in order, to your question's title, body, and tags. The message you wrote in edit #3 is incorrect, so that will need to be corrected. Ensure that you also fix the two above issues in your edit as well, and ensure you check your commands carefully this time to avoid introducing any further errors. Thanks for contributing to Arqade!

Answer (score 1):

This command works fine in 1.19.1 in Vanilla.

I'm going to assume it's not working for you due to mods you have installed. `/minecraft:give` is not a valid command in vanilla minecraft, only `/give` is. Try uninstalling all mods.

Comment: Some came and edited my question, changing the title and the body - These are not the commands that I used

Comment: I see that you have **s** at the end of  the ```lvl``` statements. Putting a letter at the end of a number makes it a float, sometimes Minecraft looks for a integer not a float. Try removing the s.